# SessionStorage.getitem not working when loading page

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue trying to use storagesession.  I have gotten it to work, but as soon as I insert some ifthen logic, it breaks.  Below is the working code.  The bottom code is when I update the window.onload function that makes it break.  Does anybody know why its breaking and how I can fix this?  I am using only html/javascript and no server is being used. Thanks so much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<ul class="vertical-nav">

<li><a href="">Fruit</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="test.html" onclick="ChangeToApple()">Apple</a></li>
<li><a href="test.html" onclick="ChangeToGrape()">Grape</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

<div id="ShowDept">

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
<script>

  window.onload = function() {
  var x = sessionStorage.getItem("Dept");


document.getElementById("ShowDept").innerHTML = x;
 }

function ChangeToApple() {
sessionStorage.Dept = "Apple";
}

function ChangeToGrape() {
sessionStorage.Dept = "Grape";
}

 </script>
```

```
  window.onload = function() {
  var x = sessionStorage.getItem("Dept");

      if (x = "Apple") {

} else if (x = "Grape") {

}
document.getElementById("ShowDept").innerHTML = x;
 }
```

Comment: Can you add a demo fiddle please

Comment: You are doing an assignment operation with `x = "Apple"`. Use `===` for comparisons, like `if (x === "Apple") { ... }`

Comment: Thank you so much Jacob.  Rookie mistake.  It works now. I figured it was something easy.  I was using the browser debugger and it didn't pick that up.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's still valid JavaScript code, unfortunately; you can have non-booleans in an if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = sessionStorage.getItem("Dept");

if (x = "Apple") {

} else if (x = "Grape") {

}
document.getElementById("ShowDept").innerHTML = x;
```

`x = "Apple"` means "Assign the string `'Apple'` to the variable `x`. It does not check if `x` equals `"Apple"`; use `x === "Apple"` for that. Because you're doing an assignment in your `if` statement, you're going to always see `Apple` in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That really helps.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
sessionStorage.Dept = "Apple";
```

try

```
sessionStorage.setItem("Dept", "Grape");
```

Comment: Thanks for the update javarip.  I have also made that update.

Comment: Strangely, this is not accurate. `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` allow you to get/set values through property accessors in addition to supporting `getItem` and `setItem`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API. I personally think `getItem` and `setItem` are _preferable_ in any case.